# Impossible to deploy Qt applications

Tags: qt, dll, deployment

I am having serious troubles in trying to deploy my new application built with Qt. The program runs fine when started from Qt Creator (all builds: debug, profile, release), but it crashes when started by double clicking on the .exe. An error dialog pops up with the following message:

> ?defaultTypeFor@QTimer@@CA?AW4TimerType@Qt@@H@Z could not be located
>   in the dynamic link library
>   C:\Users\SDT1\Documents\Scanner\Scanner_deploy\Scanner.exe

I am using Qt 5.8.0 and I am building the project with MSVC2015_64 bit. I am using windeployqt.exe from

> C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\bin

to dinamically link the Qt libraries.

This problem started happening since I moved from the old `connect` syntax (with the macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT`) to the new one with function pointers. I also started using `QTimer::singleShot` instead of `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`, and not surprising the error involves `QTimer`. However, the program works just fine from inside Qt Creator and I can't figure out where the issue is, since I am using windeployqt to get the right dlls.

Also, why my .exe is referred to as "dinamic link library" in the error message? It's an .exe!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the issue, but I'm still not sure what was going wrong: my Path variable was pointing to the folder of Qt version 5.7 (the only other version I have). I changed it to 5.8, rebooted and redeployed and it DIDN'T work. Then, I deleted the build folder, rebuilt and re-deployed and it DID work. So, the problem was with the build.

I don't know how this can happen. I changed back the Path to Qt 5.7 and rebooted to make some tests. The problem appeared again, but I don't understand how the Path affects the build. Despite having Qt 5.7 in the Path, in Qt Creator the Compile Output shows all the Qt stuff pointing to the 5.8 folder (qmake.exe, uic.exe, include folders, ...). There is no reference to version 5.7. Only jom.exe is not from the Qt 5.8 folder, since it is in the Qt Creator folder. Maybe it's it that loads something from Qt 5.7, by looking at the Path? Who knows......